# Make a python program with PySide an executable

Tags: python, exe, py2exe

I have a python program:

```
import sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtWebKit import *


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

web = QWebView()
web.load(QUrl("htpp://www.google.com"))
web.show()
web.resize(650, 750)
web.setWindowTitle('Website')

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I used google.com just for example. But if i want to make an executable of this program with py2exe but it wont work. I get this error:

[image]

With other programs without PySide it does work. But with PySide it doesnt. How can I make it work?

Comment: Format your code as code. Show the text of errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Microsoft Visual C runtime.

You should take a look at this: http://qt-project.org/wiki/Packaging_PySide_applications_on_Windows . In the py2exe tutorial it explains about the runtime you should install.

Comment: I have installed cxfreeze but if I run that cxfreeze 'cxfreeze yourapp.py blablalbla' it says that cxfreeze isnt recognised. And I dont really get it :P Kinda new to this, Python, PySide and Py2exe

Comment: @user2694647 well, cx_Freeze is a totally different beast. Have you installed the required runtime library and tried py2exe again?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a DLL. The DLL in question can be (at least formerly) obtained from Microsoft by downloading their free compiler package.

Alternatively, ensure that this process has the right paths set to find the DLL in question.